# Rails - Google Cloud messaging rpush gem

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-messaging, server-push

I am following the installation instruction of [rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) gem and I am done with migrations, then the next instruction says to write :

```
app = Rpush::Gcm::App.new
app.name = "android_app"
app.auth_key = "..."
app.connections = 1
app.save!
```

---

```
n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
n.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
n.registration_ids = ["token", "..."]
n.data = { message: "hi mom!" }
n.save!
```

I am new to rails so where exactly should i write this could and how to run it and connect it with the Android clients.

Answer (score 1):

For testig you can write it in a controller.

You can also check this blog post that contains a minimal working example of an Android App with Rails server:
http://mateuyabar.com/blog/android/rubyonrails/gcm/2015/05/13/Google-Cloud_Messaging-with-Ruby-On-Rails.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're just testing, you can create your app and notification in the Rails console.

In the future, you'll likely want to create notification in response to an event, so probably triggered in an after_save hook on a model.

The Rpush readme documents how to run Rpush.